# What is the best way to define test specs in JSON using a Ruby harness?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, minitest

I've got an interesting conundrum. I'm in the midst of developing a library to parse PSDs in Ruby. Also, a buddy is simultaneously working on a library to parse PSDs in JavaScript. We would like to share the same unit tests via a git submodule.

We've decided to use a simple JSON DSL to define each test. A single test might look like:

```
{
  "_name": "Layer should render out",
  "_file": "test/fixtures/layer_out.psd",
  "_exports_to": "test/controls/layer_out_control.png"
}
```

So, now it's up to us to build the appropriate test harnesses to translate the JSON into the appropriate native unit tests. I've been using MiniTest to get myself up to speed, but I'm running into a few walls.

Here's what I've got so far. The test harness is named `TargetPractice` for the time being:

```
# run_target_practice.rb

require 'target_practice'

TargetPractice.new(:test) do |test|
  test.pattern = "test/**/*.json"
end
```

and

```
# psd_test.rb

class PSDTest < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  attr_accessor :data

  def tests_against_data
    # do some assertions
  end
end
```

and

```
# target_practice.rb

class TargetPractice
  attr_accessor :libs, :pattern

  def initialize(sym)
    @libs = []
    @pattern = ""

    yield self

    run_tests
  end

  def run_tests
     FileList[@pattern].to_a.each do |file|
       test_data = JSON.parse(File.open(file).read)
       test = PSDTest.new(test_data["_name"]) do |t|
         t.data = test_data
       end
     end
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble getting a `yield` in the `initialize` to stick in my `PSDTest` class. Also, it appears that a test will run immediately on initialization.

I would like to dynamically create a few `MiniTest::Unit::TestCase` objects, set their appropriate data properties and then run the tests. Any pointers are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overcomplicating things a bit here. What you need is a [parameterized test](http://xunitpatterns.com/Parameterized%20Test.html), which is pretty trivial to implement using mintest/spec:

```
describe "PSD converter" do
  def self.tests(pattern = 'test/**/*.json')
    FileList[pattern].map{|file| JSON.parse(File.read(file))}
  end

  tests.each do |test|
    it "satisfies test: " + test["_name"] do
      # some assertions using test["_file"] and test["_exports_to"]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice! First time I've seen parameterized minitest/spec.